conan install can't find package but conan search does
I have a dependency between two conan packages (using conan v1).  When running conan install in the downstream package, conan can't find a dependent package satisfying certain criteria.  When I run conan search with the same critieria, however, I see the expected package.  What techniques / strategies can I use to attack this problem?
from conan install output

Cross-build from 'Macos:x86_64' to 'iOS:armv8' Installing
(downloading, building) binaries... ERROR: Missing binary:
SmartMapEngine/0.1res@navblue/stable-S-82777_export_res:53c562018ff41c00e1b32b4d605edb8e4b0ee8b2
ERROR: Missing binary:
dawn/6560@navblue/stable:509e8d6cd8fa2b4662c74e161e77c7a1fcdcf5e7
dawn/6560@navblue/stable: WARN: Can't find a
'dawn/6560@navblue/stable' package for the specified settings, options
and dependencies:

Settings: arch=armv8, build_type=Release, compiler=apple-clang, compiler.libcxx=libc++, compiler.version=15.0, os=iOS, os.version=14.0
Options: shared=False
Dependencies:
Requirements:
Package ID: 509e8d6cd8fa2b4662c74e161e77c7a1fcdcf5e7 ERROR: Missing prebuilt package for
'SmartMapEngine/0.1res@navblue/stable-S-82777_export_res',
'dawn/6560@navblue/stable'


conan search output

bash-3.2$ conan search dawn/6560@navblue/stable -r NAVBLUE-conan -q
'arch=armv8 AND build_type=Release AND compiler=apple-clang AND
compiler.libcxx=libc++ AND compiler.version=15.0 AND os=iOS AND
os.version=14.0 AND shared=False' Existing packages for recipe
dawn/6560@navblue/stable:
Existing recipe in remote 'NAVBLUE-conan':
Package_ID: fee9a0fd6216a13e33f83031540a3c4caa6c5d6a [options] shared:
False [settings] arch: armv8 build_type: Release compiler: apple-clang
compiler.libcxx: libc++ compiler.version: 15.0 os: iOS os.sdk:
iphoneos os.version: 14.0 Outdated from recipe: False


You are not using the same Conan profile when search and installing, the package ID is different in both commands. You have to use the same package ID. In case the package is not available, but only the recipe, you still can build it from source. Take a look in the official documentation: https://docs.conan.io/1/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package

Thank you for the response, but I have a question: if there is a material difference in the conan profiles, won't that be reflected in the settings, options, and requirements?  If so, I note that I used the same constraints listed in the failure message to do the conan search (which did not return empty).
I indeed observed that the package_ids are different, but I've found that the package_id (in conan v1) is based on settings, options, and requirements.
https://docs.conan.io/1/creating_packages/define_abi_compatibility.html
https://blog.conan.io/2019/09/27/package-id-modes.html

Correct, the package ID is based on settings, options and requirements. Still, you need to consider each requirement, like their settings, options and requirements too. The conan search command is agnostic to your profile and may omit data from what you using when running conan install command. To obtain information from a package that matches you profile, you can use the command conan info -r <remote>, which uses your profile and returns the same package ID as expected by conan install command.

Conan 2 has a great new command called conan graph explain (https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/commands/graph/explain.html) that helps a lot to explain when a conan instal is failing with "missing binary" error.

Thank you @uilianries, I confirm that using the same conan profile caused the same package id to be generated in search and install.
